# Eslint enforce alphabetical export order for module

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'd like to enforce alphabetical ordering of exports within a .ts file with an eslint rule in order to keep my project organized. Does such a rule exist?

So if I had three exports `a`, `c`, `b`,  like this, where the exports are not in alphabetical order:

```js
export const a = "A"
export const c = "C"
export const b = "B"
```

Eslint would warn me that the correct order is:

```js
export const a = "A"
export const b = "B"
export const c = "C"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the sort exports eslint plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-sort-exports.